# Execute shell command and use it's output in Jupyter

Tags: python, shell

I know this is a recurrent question, but I can't find a useful answer.

In Python, for running a shell command one can use [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-run-external-command-and-get-output/).

If I do the same inside Jupyter I got no output. How can I see the results
of executing the command? Doing

```
print subprocess.call(["ping", "-c 2", "www.cyberciti.biz"])
```

returns zero.

Comment: Running shell commands requires access to the OS running the Python script. Scripts in Jupyter are probably denied that access for security reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `!` shell magic:

```
!ping -c 2 www.cyberciti.biz
```

If you want to assign it to a variable:

```
output = !ping -c 2 www.cyberciti.biz
print(output)
```